# Enhancing Performance of Change History Logs in CRM App

Tags: php, mysql

I’m a completely new developer so forgive me for asking something weird but any help would be appreciated.

I’ve been assigned a feature enhancement task for an application.

The application is a CRM type application built using Core PHP / Phalcon Framework... the DB is on MySQL... it's a fully running application and needs some enhancements to existing features.

The CRM has a list of Contacts. Any user of the CRM who updates the profile of a contact, the system writes the change to it log.

There is a button called “History” when the user clicks on it, it shows the list of all changes that have been made to that particular contact… along with a couple of other information - like a revision history.

The changes are maintained and displayed from a few different tables in the DB.

The system is currently showing the changes but in plain text format.

Now the main requirement is to enhance this feature and make it look like a Facebook Timeline and also make sure that the page load times are much faster and retrieving the history of changes does not take a lot of time and does not affect performance of the CRM.

What should one do in such cases? What are the different ways to render information from different tables without affecting the performance.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting and sort of fun assignment. This question is much too broad for SO though. You'll need to invest some time into performance tuning for MySQL to understand things like indexing and the like. There is probably a myriad of solutions to each aspect of this question and each of them will depend on your existing architecture and a ton of other variables.

Comment: What sort of tuning for My SQL would be needed for example? You mentioned Indexing and like, what would be the possible options there?

Comment: It totally depends. Indexing is definitely a good place to start. Insuring that indexes are properly captured for any field on which you are joining or filtering and recognizing that indexes can cause a performance hit on write. Another option might be staging the data that is needed for this feed in a separate pre-denormalized table so that your app only needs to fetch from a single spot (reducing Joins in the SQL statements). Another option might be staging the data needed for this application in a more performant/seperate database/server so reads don't affect the main application.